# Why must we stand when counting the Omer?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sefirat-ha-omer

**The Rambam** ([Hilchos Temidim U'Mussafin, 7:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Daily_Offerings_and_Additional_Offerings.7.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) says that we must stand when counting the Omer.

The **כסף משנה** (*s.v.* "[ואין מונין אלא מעומד וכו](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Daily_Offerings_and_Additional_Offerings.7.23?lang=he&p2=Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Daily_Offerings_and_Additional_Offerings.7.23&lang2=en)") writes that the reason we must stand is based on a limud:

> כתב הר''י בן גיאת שזה קבלה מפי רבותינו ואסמכוה אקרא דבקמה קרי ביה בקומה

### Questions:

- **1)** Why do we need a special לימוד to teach us to stand by the performance of this commandment? Typically we stand when performing a commandment because of כבוד המצוה.
- **2)** Why does this particular commandment require standing?  What would be lacking in the performance of counting if we were to be sitting?
- **3)** Is there a philosophical or Halachik reason for standing when counting?

Comment: כתב הר''י בן גיאת שזה קבלה מפי רבותינו ואסמכוה אקרא דבקמה קרי ביה בקומה

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking...

Comment: you answered the first question

Comment: Does that clarify the question?

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan who says that it is Kabbalistic in nature, and that the passuk is just a cute derash to remind us...